# ejabberd send group message

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd, instant-messaging

I have ejabberd setup with a few shared rosters ("groups"). I need to be able to send messages to the entire group. I was able to do this with the built-in announce mod by sending a message to jabber.myserver.com/announce/online. This works great but it acts like a server broadcast and does not show which user the message came from.

I imagine I'm not the only one that needs to send out group messages on ejabberd, but I was surprised of the lack of documentation and solutions that I've found on this.

What would be a good way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

This would be a better question to answer fully at programming, maybe?

I would look at the mod_announce module's source code and see if you can add more URL hooks for doing something like the following for group messages:

example.com/announce/group/groupname

I don't know if this will address the need to show who sent the message, as I don't know what information is available to the module at the time of execution.  It would make sense to have the originating request accessible to the module, but I've not looked myself.

In addition, this is exactly what MUC was designed for; create a conference and invite only the users you want seeing messages sent to that conference.  You can lock it down with extensible properties provided by XMPP to keep it invitation-only and moderated; if using it for an announcement system, this might be desirable.